# Wrapper class over generic std::function

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, lambda

I am trying to write a wrapper class `foo` that takes a `std::function` as an argument and exposes a method to invoke that `std::function`. I unsuccessfully tried the following

```
template<class R, class ...Args>
class foo
{
public:
    foo(std::function<R(Args...)> f)
        :_f(f)
    {        
    }

    R invoke(Args... args)
    {
        return _f(args...);
    }

private:
    std::function<R(Args...)> _f;
};

int main()
{
    foo<void()> f([&](){ std::cout << "hi\n"; });
    f.invoke();
}
```

This doesn't compile and gives the following error

```
error C2091: function returns function
```

How can I make this work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change this:

```
foo<void()> f([&](){ std::cout << "hi\n"; });
```

to this

```
foo<void> f([&](){ std::cout << "hi\n"; });
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d700da713d1b6bb2)

Or alternatively you can parametrize `foo` with function type, like `std::function` does:

```
 template<class T>
 class foo;

 template<class R, class ...Args>
 class foo<R(Args...)> {...};

 foo<void()> f([&](){ std::cout << "hi\n"; });
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8b6cb37ca1d0cab6)